# Use Custom Layout in NavigationDrawer With Header And list

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

How to do add custom layout in `NavigationView` and design my create custom `NavigationView` use material design,i want put my drawer icon to right and text left of it something like this

[image]

Comment: You can visit this link for more information http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html

Comment: @AndroidDev i post this answer below .....

Answer (score 4):

I Search too much and this is my experience that works fine

at first create layout for header. its name is `nav_header_main.xml` then put it in `layouts` folders in `res` and put this code in it..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:gravity="top">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="16dp">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/cv_nave_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_profile_image"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_profile_image"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cv_nave_profile_image"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_nav_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="رخداد جدید"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/body"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/tv_nav_phone"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="0370077315"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

then i include it as child of `NavigationView` and For menu item i use `RecyclerView` to show menu and icon so my `NavigationView` is

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="spydroid.ir.dorobar.Activities.SearchActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_search" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nav_margin"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_slidermenu"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

just you have to remember put your `NavigationView` in `DrawerLayout`

then i create layout for menu item with `ImageView` and `TextView` this layout and this name is `card_drawer_item.xml` and its code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_about"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/drawer_icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

then i create `ViewHolder` folder for this layout.

```
public class DrawerItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView  itemIcon;
    public TextView itemText;
    public DrawerItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemIcon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);
        itemText= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_text);
    }
}
```

now i define text of menu items as string array and  array that contains menu icons in menu in `strings.xml`

```
<string-array name="drawer_items">
        <item>setting</item>
        <item>add record</item>
        <item>ads</item>
        <item>about</item>
        <item>call</item>
        <item>help</item>
        <item>privacy</item>
    </string-array>
    <array name="drawers_icons">
        <item>@drawable/ic_action_settings</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_plus</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_ads</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_about</item>

        <item>@drawable/ic_phone</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_help</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_policy</item>
    </array>
```

then we just need an `Adapter` like this

```
public class DrawerItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerItemHolder> {

    // slide menu items
    private List<DrawerItem> items;
    private List<Integer> drawerIcons;
    public DrawerItemAdapter(List<DrawerItem>  items) {
        super();
        this.items = items;


    }

    @Override
    public DrawerItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_drawer_item, parent, false);

        return new DrawerItemHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DrawerItemHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemIcon.setImageResource(items.get(position).getIconId());
        holder.itemText.setText(items.get(position).getText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

every thing is ok .. just now we have to set NavigationView in Activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
           drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

           recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_slidermenu);
        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

        String []itemsTitle=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_items);
        TypedArray icons=getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawers_icons);
        List<DrawerItem>drawerItems= new  ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        for(int i=0;i<itemsTitle.length;i++){
                drawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(icons.getResourceId(i,-1),itemsTitle[i]));
        }

        DrawerItemAdapter ad= new DrawerItemAdapter(drawerItems);
        recList.setAdapter(ad);

    }

     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```